# Trying to get http connection to OrientDB error 505

Tags: android, http, orientdb

I am trying to make a http connection from an android device to OrientDB running on a Linux server. I receive a response code of 505 HTTP version not supported. I don't think there is a version problem. The Curl command work with the -0 option set, I am trying to "connect" to the database using the following as my connect http string:

myUrl is a String its value is :
http://192.168.1.67:2480/connect/GratefulDeadConcerts

The command:

curl -u root:root http://192.168.1.67:2480/connect/GratefulDeadConcerts

Works.

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
    String contentAsString = null;
    String userpass = "Basic" + "root" + ":" + "root12";
    String basicAuth = new         String(Base64.encode(userpass.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)        url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "1024");

        // Query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Logging.log("Connection", "The respond code is:" + response);
        //is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a Stream

        //contentAsString = readIt(is, len);


    }
```

Comment: What exactly is `myUrl` in your code? How is it defined?

Comment: Also, Server logs show nothing.

Comment: Here is its definition      private String downLoadUrl(String myUrl) throws IOException {

Comment: Sorry myUrl's value is http://192.168.1.67:2480/connect/GratefulDeadConcerts

Comment: Please edit the question instead of using comments, that's more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the base64 conversion of userpass.
Try this:

```
String userpass = "root" + ":" + "root12";
```

and then the authorization property:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ basicAuth);
```

Comment: Thanks this was the problem. I had tried the prefixing the "Basic"  in some of my attempt But I guest I include a ':', Thanks so much and Cheers